# Not able to connect embedded firebird database using node js

Tags: node.js, firebird, node-firebird

I am using node-firebird javascript client for Firebird database. I am not able to connect Firebird database using node-firebird client. I have embedded firebird database. I am getting below error :

NodeJS firebird client : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird

> E:\NodeJS\Firebird\demo.js:20
>           throw err;
>           ^ undefined

Code :

```
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');

var options = {};

options.host = '127.0.0.1';
options.port = 3050;


options.database = 'E:\\NodeJS\\Firebird\\Firebird_3_0_Embedded\\examples\\empbuild\\EMPLOYEE.FDB';
//options.lowercase_keys = true; // set to true to lowercase keys
options.role = null;            // default
options.pageSize = 4096;        // default when creating database

Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {

    if (err)
        console.log("Error :"+err);
        throw err;

 console.log("CONNECT SUCCESSFULLY");

    // db = DATABASE
    db.query('SELECT * FROM user', function(err, result) {
        // IMPORTANT: close the connection
        console.log(result);
        db.detach();
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to connect embedded firebird database using NodeJS

Comment: You need to use a block after your if. So `if (err) { log...; throw err;}` currently the `throw err` is executed unconditionally, including when `err` is not defined. In JavaScript indentation is not significant (contrary to Python). Voting to close as off topic due to typo.

Comment: Additionally, `options.host = '127.0.0.1'; options.port = 3050;` - this means you are NOT using embedded Firebird, you use (or attempt to use) a full-fledged stand-alone server running outside of NodeJS process and connected by TCP/IP v4 network protocol.